# Restoring from oracle incomplete cold backup

Tags: database, oracle, data-recovery

My Database is running in No-Archive Log mode. Control files and redo log files are multiplexed on two drives, say A and B. C drive has the rest of the files.
I did a cold backup and did only A and C (no B).
Now, when restoring, I copied control file from A do B. That was ok with control files to go further. But what to do with redo logs which are missing on B?Actually I have on B more recent logs, remaining from the scrapped database - they don't match the cold backup, so I am sure I can drop them but I didn't so far.
I can go as far as to MOUNT. When trying to open database - end of channel communication error. Alter database open resetlogs wants me to do recovery first. Recovery is not working.
Is this a result, that I kept on B non matching redo logs or would it be something different? I thought I would be able to open a database with one member in each redo group being corrupted (B drive) and one being fine (A drive redo logs).
Is there other option than re-create control files (which I have) and open with resetlogs?
It is oracle 12.1.0.1. I will check my trace file but I was thinking about something obvious here.

Comment: (a) this kind of question is better suited to http://dba.stackexchange.com/, (b) when you say 'recovery is not working', exactly what do you mean?  What command(s) have you attempted and exactly what is the output?

Comment: You could try to run an incomplete recovery a-la: RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL and then open with resetlogs. Probably move the newer redos off the B-drive location before that.

Comment: This morning I removed non maching B drive redo logs ,then startup MOUNT; RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL, then alter database open resetlogs ... and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Just to help with more understanding. In your scenario/setup, your redo logs (also known as on-line redo logs) are only used for instance recovery (a database crash) - not restore/recovery. You are taking cold backups, as that's all you can do in this mode. On-line redo logs are never backed up. So to recover, simply copy the database files back, and start the database up. If you're missing controlfiles, do what you did, copy from an existing location or remove from your pfile/spfile and up you go. Cold backups should not require "open resetlogs". That's PIT recovery, which you can't do.

Comment: If your database isn't that busy and you haven't switched logs beyond your on-line logs, when you do a restore, they can be used to roll forward from your backup. Once you loop around your on-line logs and overwrite information in any one of them, you lose the ability to do anything but restore to the exact point in time of your cold backup. Be sure to restore your backed up control files over the existing ones so that PIT recovery is not assumed (as your existing ones will have information regarding additional logs that are not available to you).